# Put a print in a method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Can we put a print in a method of class? (PEP8)
I know it is better to make a return. But I have to turn a big python file into a class ...

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.r = str

    def tester(self):
        print('hello')
        print(self.name)

r = Test('pascal')
r.tester()
```

Comment: What issues are you currently experiencing?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can't you just run that code and find out?

Comment: I just revisited PEP8; I can't see anything about `print` specifically.

Comment: "I know it is better to make a return." - correct

Comment: I have to turn a big file into a class. I would like to know if the convention makes it possible to put a print in a class method or we should totally banish this. and instead use a return that I then display with a print. The file is really big, to transcribe

Comment: A method that prints stuff is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @PascaldeSélys There really is not enough info to answer that. `print` is slow, but it's no faster if you `return` the value and then `print` it. You possibly want to update an attribute for each object and, with a counter of iterations, use `if iternation_num % 1000 == 0: print(something)`. In other words, have a periodic printed output.

Comment: All right, thank you for your answers:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to directly answer your question, Yes. You can put a print statement in a class.  You are also correct that it is better to use a return statement so as to conform more towards portability and reusability.

However, I'm going to make an assumption here that what you are actually looking for is a way to return a string representation of the state of the class.

This is where the function `__str__` comes in.  [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str__#object.__str__)

In your case you would

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        #self.r = str <-I don't know where "str" is coming from

    def __str__(self):
        return "Hello {0}".format(self.name)
```

Now you can instantiate the class

```
r = Test("pascal")
```

and print it

```
print(r)
```

to get

```
Hello pascal
>>>
```